# Probability that $a^2+b^2+c^2$ divisible by $7$

Tags: probability

> Three numbers $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ are choosen randomly from the set of natural numbers. The probability that $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is divisible by $7$ is

Try:any natural number when divided by $7$ gives femainder $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$

So it is in the form of $7k,7k+1,7k+2\cdots ,7k+6,$ where $k\in \mathbb{W}$

Could some help me to how to solve it, thanks

Comment: "...are chosen randomly from the set of natural numbers." Does this mean "uniformly randomly"? If so, that's not possible. And if not...then the answer is "it depends on the distribution." In short: this question does not have an answer.

Comment: @JohnHughes I suppose one could say that they are chosen uniformly from the range $1$ to $N$, and then take the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: You **could**  say that, but you could also say that $a$ was either 1 or 6, based on a coin flip, $b$ was either $2$ or $5$, again on a coin-flip, and $c$ was either $3$ or $4$. Then the sum of the squared residuals is *always* $7$ and the probability is one. As stated, the problem doesn't favor either of these interpretations. Hence my initial comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What remainders do the squares of numbers give when divided by 7 these are $$(7k)^2 \rightarrow 0 \\ (7k+1)^2 \rightarrow 1 \\ (7k+2)^2 \rightarrow 4 \\ (7k+3)^2 \rightarrow 2 \\ (7k+4)^2 \rightarrow 2 \\ (7k+5)^2 \rightarrow 4 \\(7k+6)^2 \rightarrow 1 \\$$

Now the sum of remainders must add upto a multiple of 7, this can happen if remainders are $(0,0,0), (1,2,4)$

The first case of remainders can be chosen in $\frac{1}{7^3}$

**Edit**

Doing corrections by mike and almagest
The second case can be written in $3!$ ways, and probability of each being $\frac8{343}$, the probability of second case is $3!\cdot\frac8{343}=\frac{48}{343}$

And total probability comes to be $\frac17$

Comment: This seems to be assuming a uniformly random distribution on $x, y, z$; there is no such distribution.

Comment: I can see that there can't be any distribution that is uniformly random on natural numbers but, remainders when divided by 7 is a well defined distribution don't you think?

Comment: Well, for any distribution on the naturals, we also get a distribution on the remainders. But why should this "quotient" distribution be uniform over the remainders? Perhaps you're thinking that implicit in the question is that the quotient distribution is uniform, but I have a hard time reading that into what's written.

Comment: @piyush divyankar i did not understand how you written $\displaystyle \frac{1.2.2}{7.7.7}$ explain please.thanks

Comment: Let's say that we have the set ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7}$ of naturals. If we randomly pick from this set where each element is equally likely to be picked then we get that distribution of remainders should be uniform now let's say the we are picking from a set $\mathrm{N}_k$ where $k\ge7$. It is obvious that as we make $k$ larger and larger the distribution of remainders gets closer to uniform distribution. So it must be true for a randomly picked natural number to have remainders uniformly distributed . Does that not make sense?

Comment: Don't the remainders repeat themselves after 7k+3 . Then what is the need to consider their permutations

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari Oops, I corrected it. You need to have remainders 1, 2, 4 to have them sum up to 7 and be divisible by 7. The chance of getting each of these remainders is $\frac27$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second half is not correct.  Firstly, $2^3\ne6$.  Secondly, does it cover the scenario $(4,1,2)$?

Comment: First case fine. 2nd case: 1st number can be anything but 0, is 6/7, then 4 choices for 2nd number (not 0 or 1st num or 7-1st num), then 2 choices for last number, so final answer should be (1+48)/343=1/7. That makes me wonder if there is a neater solution!

Comment: I think the probability should be $\frac {2}{20} = \frac {1}{10}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint

Any perfect square $x$ Is

$x\equiv 0\pmod 7$

Or

$x\equiv 1\pmod 7$

Or

$x\equiv 2\pmod 7$

Or

$x\equiv 4\pmod 7$